# Link to product category dynamically

Tags: dynamic, redirect

I need link to product category dynamically like:

```
 http://example.com/product-category/?product_cat=category-name
```

And it redirect to product category archive, how can I do that?

Comment: it would be cool if you at least give us the language you're using or web server if you want it to be redirect on webserver level (though i assume its not that)

Comment: No, I need add it to button in wordpress only, no server side. I need specific part after "?" so it must display category name.